# Passing a parameter's value to shell function prints only the name of the parameter

Tags: bash, shell, docker, parameters

I need to pass a parameter to my shell function, which looks like this:

```
function deploy {

        docker create \
        --name=$1_temp \
        -e test_postgres_database=$2 \
        -e test_publicAddress="http://${3}:9696"\
        # other irrelevant stuff
```

I am passing the following parameters:

`deploy test_container test_name #1 test_database #2 ip_address #3`

So when, I pass those 3 parameters, based on them a new container is created. However, the third parameter is something special. So there is another function, which gets the ip of the container.

```
function get_container_ip_address {
    container_id=($(docker ps --format "{{.ID}} {{.Names}}" | grep $1))
    echo $(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' ${container_id[0]})
```

So, the execution of the deploy function actually looks like this:

```
ip_address=$(get_container_ip_address test_container)
deploy test_container test_database ip_address
```

Let's say the IP address of the container is 1.1.1.1, so the `ip_address=1.1.1.1`.
However, when I execute the script and create the container, its IP address is:
`"http://ip_address:9696"` and not `"http://1.1.1.1:9696"`.

I also tried the following:

```
...
-e test_publicAddress="http://$3:9696"\
...
```

But I still got the same result. Is there a way I can get the value of the passed parameter? By the way, I am sure it contains the needed ip address as I use it elsewhere (not in a function) and I printed it for testing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you pass only `1.1.1.1` or `ip_address 1.1.1.1` to script ?

Comment: @LinPy Basically, I execute `ip_address=$(get_container_ip_address test_container)` and directly after it, `deploy test_container test_database ip_address` (which executes the deploy function with those 3 parameters - name, database, ip_address). So at this point `ip_address` should have `1.1.1.1` as a value (I have tested this on other places in the code, and it prints it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so run this like that:

```
ip_address=$(get_container_ip_address test_container)

deploy test_container test_database $ip_address
```

when you call it without the `$` the script leave it alone like a string `ip_address`

Comment: You (almost) always put double-quotes around variable references, so use `"$ip_address"` instead of just `$ip_address`. It won't matter for an IP address (unless someone's playing weird games with `IFS`), but unquoted variable references are a bad habit.